# Can't find reason for Serif WebPlus X5 error message:

Tags: xml, web

I purchased Webplus X5 today and unfortunately I keep getting an error message.

When Webplus opens, it works fine but when I click on 'use design template':

I get the "Failed to initialize Microsoft XML. Please Check Your Installation" error message.

And again I get it, when I drag and drop things off the lower toolbar like a button or a navigation bar.
I checked a couple of forums off Serif for the same error but none helped- one suggested I download the lastest version of MSXML from microsoft but I alreadly have MSXML 3.0 SP 11, MSXML 4.0 SP 2 and MSXML 6.0 SP 3, which should be more than sufficient. I also tried uninstalling all Serif programs and reinstalling them.
I also downloaded an update for webplus X5 off Serif's website..
-Still nothing

please help.

Answer (score 1):

It is not the Microsoft XML package, it is the software itself. It has not been successfully installed. This happened to me when I had purchased it. All you need to do is reinstall the software. Login into Serif, and re-download the software. Hope this helps.

Or it could be what operating system you are using.